# Python3 How to replace some html tags use re

Tags: python-3.x

I want to quote contents with `{{` and `}}` which in html tag like `strong/b/u` use Python3, How to implement it ?

```
import re
n_start = ' {{'
n_end = '}} '
for tag in 'strong', 'u', 'b':
    pat = r'<' + tag + '[^><]*>(.*?)</' + tag + '>'
    html = re.sub(pat, lambda x: n_start + str(x.group(1)).strip() + n_end, html,
                  flags=re.I | re.S | re.M)
```

---

I want to replace html code from `<u style="border:xxxx">AAA</u>` to `<u style="border:xxxx">{{AAA}}</u>`,html tag is  `strong` or `b` or `u`

Comment: please add a little more info, an example of your input and your desired output would be nice.

Comment: I think you could use the `html.parser` from [the python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html) to add the opening/closing braces when discovering the desired start/end tags.